# Нужна ли запятая перед "почему"?

Tags: пунктуация

"На этот раз все получилось, и я понял(,) почему".

Answer (score 1):

Запятая **НЕ нужна**, так как придаточная часть состоит из одного союзного слова.

Answer (score 1):

В качестве иллюстрации к правильному ответу Ларf:
***Не ставится запятая между главным и следующим за ним придаточным предложением:***
а)       если перед подчинительным союзом или союзным словом стоит отрицание не, например: Попытайтесь выяснить не что они уже сделали, а что они собираются еще сделать; Я пришел не чтобы помешать вам, а, наоборот, чтобы помочь;
б)       если перед подчинительным союзом или союзным слоном стоит сочинительный союз (обычно повторяющийся) и, или, либо и т.п., например: Учтите и что он сказал, и как он это сказал; Студент не мог вспомнить ни как называется произведение, ни кто его автор;
в)       ***если придаточное предложение состоит из одного только союзного слова (относительного местоимения или наречия), например: Меня упрекают, но не знаю в чем; Уходя, он обещал скоро вернуться, но не уточнил когда; Мать температуру определяла губами: приложит губы ко лбу и сразу определит сколько.*** (http://www.classes.ru/grammar/127.Rosental-pravopisanie/49.htm)

Answer (score 0):

"Почему" будет обычным дополнением?  Понял (что?) почему?

Comment: Союзное слово "почему" присоединяет придаточное дополнительное (изъяснительное). Но предложение неполное, состоит только их одного слова.